# undefined variable and property of non-object in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm getting these two error messages for my 3 variables:

message 1) Undefined variable: rows
message 2) Trying to get property of non-object

EDIT: (finally found the edit button), so the 3 variables are:

```
        $anatomic_code = $rows->NerveCode;
        $ProxAccess = $rows->ProxAccess;
        $DistAccess = $rows->DistAccess;
```

Which can be found in my view, it is the above 3 lines that are giving me the two errors.

I have not included the model as I don't think the problem is there, and more so because its quite some code due to the developers before me has used lots of different tables storing the data in... however I'm ready to post it if needed.

Controller ->

```
function se_enkel_test()
    {
    $this->freakauth_light->check('submitter');
    $tech_num = $this->uri->segment(6);
    $this->load->model('view_single_test','',true);
    $data['query'] = $this->view_single_test->query();
    $data['query_tech_type'] =  $this->view_single_test->query_tech_type();
    $data['query_parameters'] =  $this->view_single_test->query_parameters();
    $data['query_tech_name'] =  $this->view_single_test->query_tech_name();
    $data['query_test'] =  $this->view_single_test->query_test();
    $data['query_temperat'] =  $this->view_single_test->query_temperat();
    $data['query_semiq'] =  $this->view_single_test->query_semiq();
    $data['query_conclusion'] =  $this->view_single_test->query_conclusion();
    $data['query_side'] =  $this->view_single_test->query_side();

    $this->load->model('mysql_create','',true);
    $data['dropdown_conclusion_diagnosis'] = $this->mysql_create->get_dropdown_conclusion($tech_num);
    $data['dropdown_conclusion_duration'] = $this->mysql_create->get_dropdown_duration_diagnosis();
    $data['dropdown_conclusion_severity'] = $this->mysql_create->get_dropdown_severity_diagnosis();

    $this->load->view('auh/se_enkel_test', $data);
    }
```

View ->

```
elseif ($struct_id == "3") {

            foreach($query->result() as $rows):
            if ($rows->NerveCode > 10000 ){
                echo "<h3>N." . $rows->NerveName . ") (" . $side->SideText.")</h3>";        

            }
            else {
                echo "<h3>N." . $rows->NerveName . " (" . $rows->ProxName . " - ";
                    if ($rows->Code < 3000) {
                        echo "m.";
                        }
                    echo $rows->DistName . ") ("  . $side->SideText.")</h3>";
            }
            endforeach;
            $anatomic_code = $rows->NerveCode;
            $ProxAccess = $rows->ProxAccess;
            $DistAccess = $rows->DistAccess;
    }
```

[This is how my page looks now facing the errors, one should be aware there several errors above this page, as stated earlier in the post. but the same two errors for all 3 variables.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMmlf.png)

[This is how the original page used to look.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Vl92.png)

From the two screenshots you can see that the problem on my page is I'm not getting the "length of segment" value.. and the muscle name: 
"N.peroneus (ankle - m.extensor digitorum brevis) (sin.)"

The model with function "query" ->

```
function query()
{
    $exam = $this->uri->segment(3);    
    $type_id = $this->uri->segment(4);
    $struct_id = $this->uri->segment(5);    
    $technique_id = $this->uri->segment(6);
    $test_id = $this->uri->segment(7);
        switch($type_id)
        {
            case 1:
                $query_input = "SELECT EMUSCLE.*, NERVMUSCACCP.NAME AS MuscleName, NERVMUSCACCP.ShortName AS ShortMuscleName FROM EMUSCLE,NERVMUSCACCP WHERE Exam = ".$exam." AND Struct = ".$struct_id." AND EMUSCLE.MuscleCode = NERVMUSCACCP.Code;";
                break;
            case 2:
                $query_input = "SELECT ENERVE.*, NERVMUSCACCP.NAME AS NerveName, NERVMUSCACCP.ShortName AS ShortNerveName FROM ENERVE,NERVMUSCACCP WHERE Exam = ".$exam." AND Struct = ".$struct_id." AND ENERVE.NerveCode = NERVMUSCACCP.Code;";
                break;
            case 3:
                $query_input = "SELECT NewTable2.*, prox2.Code, prox2.Name AS DistName, prox2.ShortAccPName AS ShortDistName FROM (SELECT NewTable1.*, prox.Name AS ProxName, prox.ShortAccPName AS ShortProxName FROM (SELECT es.*,  NERVMUSCACCP.NAME AS NerveName, NERVMUSCACCP.ShortName AS ShortNerveName FROM ESEGMENT es, NERVMUSCACCP WHERE Exam = ".$exam." AND Struct = ".$struct_id." AND es.NerveCode = NERVMUSCACCP.Code) AS NewTable1 LEFT OUTER JOIN PROXDISTINFO prox ON NewTable1.ProxAccess = prox.Code) AS NewTable2 LEFT OUTER JOIN PROXDISTINFO prox2 ON NewTable2.DistAccess = prox2.Code;";
                break;
            case 4:
                $query_input = "SELECT NewTable1.*, NERVMUSCACCP.NAME AS MuscleName, NERVMUSCACCP.ShortName AS ShortMuscleName FROM (SELECT EJNCTION.*, NERVMUSCACCP.NAME AS NerveName, NERVMUSCACCP.ShortName AS ShortNerveName FROM EJNCTION LEFT OUTER JOIN NERVMUSCACCP ON EJNCTION.NerveCode = NERVMUSCACCP.Code WHERE EJNCTION.Exam = ".$exam." AND Struct = ".$struct_id.") AS NewTable1 LEFT OUTER JOIN NERVMUSCACCP ON NewTable1.MuscleCode = NERVMUSCACCP.Code";
                break;
        }    
    $query = $this->db->query($query_input);

    return $query;
}
```

Comment: The error message says that $rows is not defined, meaning that $query->result() has no rows. Where do you perform the query? Are you sure you're getting anything out of the db and the query is correct?

Comment: Have you _researched_ the error messages? They get discussed all the time, and if they are not pretty self-explanatory to you already, then the explanations in one of the existing answers should be able to help you understand what is going on.

Comment: As for your asking here, please go read [ask] first of all. Telling us that you _get_ errors, without telling us _where_, resp. regarding which variables/objects on what lines, is not really helpful. Quote error messages verbatim!

Comment: I simple forgot as I was so focused on getting the code in there. Now I can't figure out how to "edit" the post to let you guys know the lines.. I'm sorry.
Edit; I found the edit button and now have updated the post. Very sorry for that

Comment: bottom left of your question

Comment: @Alberto the query is in my model, and it should be. It's very hard for me to say, because I've been handed this old project made by other programmers, and they have left no comments or any guidance... however all the other data on the page is working except those 3 variables.. so I'm still getting lots of data that is working

Comment: @misorude  Yes, I have researched and researched the last two days, tried all the different stackoverflows answers I could find.. 

I'm actually so confused that I had a hard time even asking this question if that makes sense..

Comment: The basis of such a loop over a database query result is, that `$query->result()` will return `false` after the last record has been processed - that is what makes the loop terminate. So _after_ your loop, `$row` will be simply `false`. `false` isn’t an object with any additional properties, yet you still try and access properties on that variable _after_ your loop.

Comment: So I should "endforeach" after I try to access those 3 variables?

Comment: Depends on what you actually need. If you move the endforeach after those three lines, then those variables will contain the column values from the _last_ record, when you access them to read the values back later _after_ your loop. Whether that is what you _need_, is impossible for us to tell at this point.

Comment: I will update the post with two screenshots in a minute, I hope that can help show what my problem is. I can see that I failed to explain this tremendous, I once again apologize for that and I do appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not actually passing the query result to the view:

```
$data['query'] = $this->view_single_test->query();
```

Without seeing the model it's hard to make an educated guess. The value assigned to $data['query'] should be the result object. 
Not the cleanest, but try this returning `$query->result();` from the model and assign that to a variable in the controller which is then passed on to the view.

Comment: I uploaded the part of my model where the "query" is made.  Maybe that helps? 
I'm not sure what you mean by $query->result(); from the model.

Comment: Try returning $query->result(); instead of just $query;

Comment: That gives me this error: Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on array

Comment: When you started returning `$query->result()`, did you remember to change `$query->result()` for just `$query` in the view?

Comment: In my view im calling the query inside of a foreach loop, how would the syntax look like? I tried simply delete "->result()" so it just says $query. But then I get an "fatal error".. and it says I can't call that in a foreach loop.. 
Thank you for trying so hard to help me, I appreciate it!

Comment: If you return `$query->result()` from the model and you assign the returned result to a variable in the controller which is then passed on to the view (i.e., `$results = $this->model->function()` ), then on the view you can iterate with `foreach ($results as $res)` and access the data on each row by doing `$res->fieldname`. If you don't want to iterate but need to access a specific row, you can do so with `$res[0]->fieldname` (0 is the first row, 1 is the second and so on)